# seems that my where statement in sql is being ignored?

Tags: mysql

i have a query that returns a score for each item listed in a table that has the year earlier than 1980. I have a similar one for years after 1980. when i try to compute the average of one minus the average the other, it for some reason is computing the averages as the same (so as to be ignoring my  where clause. am i doing something wrong?

```
Select avg(stars) 
from
(Select stars
from Rating, Movie 
where movie.mid = rating.mid and movie.year < 1980);
```

Comment: what good is the subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Change your cartesian product join to a regular join would be the first step... we need to see some data to understand the question better... but heres a first pass

```
SELECT AVG(stars)
FROM movie
JOIN rating ON rating.mid = movie.mid
WHERE movie.year < 1980
GROUP BY movie.mid
```

if this doesn't work then please post some data so I can test it

Comment: I think a `group by` clause will not go amiss

Comment: @EdHeal thanks yea i forgot to add that in with the aggregate function lol thanks for the comment